# Why is BUILD_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY not getting set?

Tags: bazel

I'm using `bazel` `5.1.0` and have the following in a `BUILD` file:

```
sh_binary(
    name = "aoeu",
    srcs = ["aoeu.sh"]
)
```

The contents of `aoeu.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "BAZEL_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY=${BAZEL_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY}"
```

When I `bazel run aoeu`, the output is `BAZEL_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY=`.

Based on https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html, my understanding is that `BAZEL_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY` should be set. Why isn't it?

Comment: Running `env` or `export` would be one way to tackle this. Also, if this is caused by Bazel docs that were wrong, please file a bug ticket!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired environmental variable is called `BUILD_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY` not `BAZEL_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: Doh! Guess I had copied and pasted from other code and not straight from the docs.